# PostGIS Functions not working using hibernate in java?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, postgis

I need to execute select `ST_AsText(column_name)` from table using hibernate createSQlQuery().

When i executed that query, it fires an `exception`.

But when i execute the same query using simple JDBC or in my `PGAdmin browser`, the query works.

Below is my query:

```
select st_astext(linkPoints) from linkRoute
```

Exception:

```
SEVERE: ERROR: relation "linkroute" does not exist
```

Mapping File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.lnt.utility.pojo.linkRoute" table="link_route">
    <id name="Id" column="id">
    <generator class="assigned" />
  </id>
    <property name="linkName" column="link_name"/>
    <property name="distance" column="distance"/>
    <property name="idNo" column="idno"/>
    <property name="speed" column="speed"/>
    <property name="linkPoints" column="link_points"/>

</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hibernate provide a createSQLQuery method to let you call your native SQL statement directly.**

I hope you should be able to work with your query using nativequery else you should go for Hibernate Spatial.

Please find the [link](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-native-sql-queries-examples/) for more information on hibernate native query tutorial. Hope this helps.